# Render more-like-this view from button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, blacklight

I want to create a button from the search result from Solr (7.5.0) in Blacklight (7.0.1) which on click should render a more-like-this view.

I have tried to include the button in the catalog_controller and calling the more-like-this view through a helper function. 
Also tried to direct the routes in the routes.rb.

The catalog_controller:

```
config.add_index_field 'id', helper_method: :more_like_this
```

The helper function

```
def more_like_this
render_document_sidebar_partial
end
```

catalog_helper_behavior.rb

```
def render_document_sidebar_partial(_document = @document)
  render partial: 'show_sidebar'
end
```

Gives me the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bookmarks", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

How do I pass the id correctly?

I simply want Blacklight to render the more-like-this view in the right sidebar when the button is pushed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to add your `show_sidebar` partial to your question. In that, you're probably calling a path helper (maybe `bookmark_path`?) but are not passing an `id` to the helper. That may be because you're calling `render partial:` without any `locals`. Hard to say.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I pass the locals? Benjamins suggestion below did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are problems in what you've posted:
1. the show_sidebar partial expects to have a local called document, so should be called with something like:

```
 render partial: "show_sidebar", locals: { document: _document }
```

2. the helper_method configuration for Blacklight fields identifies a method that expects to be called with an argument hash that minimally has a :document key for the SolrDocument and a :field key for the field name - the `more_like_this` method is a Rails helper (that is, it returns an html_safe string), not a Blacklight field value helper.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but now I am getting undefined local variable or method `_document' where should this be defined?

Comment: the method you posted had a parameter called _document; is it possible you changed the name in response to a rubocop instruction?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are missing the `index` action for bookmarks (in your routes and maybe in your controller).

the url you are going to is probably `/bookmarks` but you only have something like `get "/bookmarks/:id"` in your routes so it's not finding the required `:id` parameter.